# UDP Server Restart every 5 seconds

Tags: c++, udp, winsock

I am writing for the first time in this language and could only write this 
 UDP server and client. I need help; I want to  server waits for a response and displays it. If within 5 sec. the answer is not received, the program starts its execution again.If you don't understand task, you can translate task(fifth) :https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/socket/node15.html

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
    using namespace std;
    void main()
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        fd_set fd;
        WSADATA data;
        WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
        cout << "Server opened" << endl;
        if (wsOk != 0)
        {
            cout << "Can't start Winsock! " << wsOk;
            return;
        }
        SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        sockaddr_in serverHint;
        serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY; 
        serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        serverHint.sin_port = htons(54000); 
        if (bind(in, (sockaddr*)& serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Can't bind socket! " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            return;
        }
        sockaddr_in client; 
        int clientLength = sizeof(client); 
        char buf[1024];
        while (true)
        {

            FD_ZERO(&fd);
            FD_SET(in, &fd);
            tv.tv_sec = 5;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;
            if (select(0, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
            {
                ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength);
                ZeroMemory(buf, 1024);
                int bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buf, 1024, 0, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientLength);
                if (bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    cout << "Error receiving from client " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                    continue;
                }
                char clientIp[256];
                ZeroMemory(clientIp, 256);
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIp, 256);
                cout << "Message recv from " << clientIp << " : " << buf << endl;

            }
            else  {
                cout << "Timeout" << endl;
                closesocket(in);
                break;

            }
            closesocket(in);
            WSACleanup();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You start a server and if it doesn't receive a message within 5 seconds, it should restart? What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Why? Why not just receive in a loop? With a receive timeout? What's the benefit of restarting the entire process?

Comment: Create a Thread that loops around a wait on an auto reset event with a 5000 timeout and have the server thread set the event upon every datagram receipt.  If the wait times out, call ExitProcess().  Run the server exe in a batch file loop.  Also, as above, please explain your strange requirement a bit clearer?

Comment: That's a very strange design. Are you sure you have understood the task correctly? Anyway, you could use `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` to wait for a message with a timeout and do whatever you like if it times out instead of getting a message.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there has been some miscommunication of what you're expected to do.

Comment: Guys, he doesn't need an event, just a read timeout on the socket.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set fd;
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    cout << "5" << endl;
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cout << "Winsock" << wsOk;
        return;
    }
    SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in serverHint;
    serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY; 
    serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serverHint.sin_port = htons(54000); 
    if (bind(in, (sockaddr*)& serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "hhhh" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }
    sockaddr_in client; 
    int clientLength = sizeof(client); 
    char buf[1024];
    while (true)
    {

        FD_ZERO(&fd);
        FD_SET(in, &fd);
        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        if (select(0, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength);
            ZeroMemory(buf, 1024);
            int bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buf, 1024, 0, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientLength);
            if (bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "EEEROOR" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                continue;
            }
            char clientIp[256];
            ZeroMemory(clientIp, 256);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIp, 256);
            cout << "С " << clientIp << " : " << buf << endl;
            closesocket(in);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0);
        }
        else  {
            cout << "jhkjhkjhjn" << endl;
            closesocket(in);
            main();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Translation of the task by google translate:

> 1. Write a program that asks the user for an IP address, port number and text string,
> 2. sends a string to the specified address using the UDP protocol,
> 3. waits for a response, and displays it on the screen.
>
>    - If within 5 sec. the answer is not received, the program starts its execution again.

Your program is completely missing part 1 and 2 so you must add those.

For part 3, move your current `while` loop so it covers everything in `main`:

```
int main() // note: main must be declared to return 'int'
{
    while(true) { // new start of the while loop, first in main

            // ... your current code until the below line ...

            cout << "Message recv from " << clientIp << " : " << buf << endl;

            // exit program if you've received a response
            closesocket(in);
            break; // break out of while loop
        }
        else {
            cout << "Timeout" << endl;
        }

        closesocket(in);
        WSACleanup();

    } // end of while loop

    WSACleanup();
} // end of main
```

This reinitializer Winsock2 for every try which is unnecessary and it also has `closesocket` in multiple places. I would add classes for both `WSAStartup`/`WSACleanup` and `socket`/`closesocket` to manage the resources they have acquire.

Comment: sorry this did not help because the program now restarts although instead of a break it should be closing the socket and main () as a function call but when the client writes a message the server restart also although it should close how to write new if  which message received from client=>close socket

Comment: The way the translation of the task comes through (to Swedish), I do _not_ interpret it as the program necessarily needs to restart itself. If that's really needed, call `CreateProcess` to start another instance of the program and then terminate the first instance. This kind of behaviour is not good though. If something goes wrong, you'll have a really hard time to kill the process (since you'll get new process id:s for every iteration - fast). Anyway, that's how you can do it. :-)

Comment: i think what i must write one condition if message received from client =>close socket

Comment: Well, there are a few things missing in your code to fulfil the task - but your question is about restarting the server (either the complete program _or_ the instance of the UDP server inside the program).

Comment: Ok, good, then the current `while` loop I added should work. If you _do_ receive a message I'm guessing you should release all resources (like sockets) and terminate the program. The task doesn't specify what to do in that case exactly.

Comment: can you write full code because i think i I wrote the same way you said, look in the edited code

Comment: You are not allowed to call `main`. You haven't added the while loop I suggested. With that loop and the `break` you dont need to call main.

Comment: I don't understand write plz full code because i added loop while(true)

Comment: This isn't really a code writing service - especially not when it comes to school assignments. Look at my answer and compare it with your code. Do you see any difference?

Comment: my code looks like yours or i can add new while(true) and what should be in this loop and only if i added break instead of main() my program after timeout broke

Comment: Your code is missing the added while loop and break that my answer was all about. Also, my answer does not contain a call to main - since that is forbidden. Read above my code where the while loop should be placed.

Comment: look my code again in my code stand break but i don't understand what i must write in missing while loop or i must write second while(true) identity first can you write new while loop pleaze i know what he tried to help me i thank you for that

Comment: If you get a timeout now - what happens? Your program terminates, right? Where would you put a while loop to make it restart it all again? There is another problem with your code too but we'll deal with that later.

Comment: Btw: have you learnt to write classes? Your program could use one or two for resource management.

Comment: i really don't konw where and what included in this loop please help I do not ask you to write the code completely; I ask you to write a new loop and where it should be please help me

Comment: I'm new to C++, I don’t know how to write classes please help me

Comment: I'll be back to the computer in 5-7 hours and will look at how the code in your question looks then and try to walk you through how to finaluze it step by step. If I add some small classes, will that be ok?

Comment: Thanks! About classes. If I should add one or two simple ones, it will change the program a bit - but simplify the flow. Have you written any classes yet?

Comment: No, which classes must i write and  why do my program need classes?? I think my programm is very short i would write functions instead of classes I think this is simple for example 1 and 2 part for my code before while in one function and  my timer second function or not??

Comment: Classes helps with resource management. Properly written it will let someone who is making an application, like you, concentrate on the logic of the app, and pretty much forget about about closing a socket or releasing other resources in one of 350 ways the program might go. What's left is like lego. Building the lego pieces is what classes are for.

Comment: i think i need in two classes:First class- 1part and 2part my programm and second_class:This is my Timer or not,and in my home task is necessarily that i use winapi library and your functions in my programm this is WS2tcpip.h or we can use winsock or other libraries to write socket server with winapi

Comment: I won't be able to find time to tackle it tonight, but don't think about tasks as classes. Think about resources. You Open - you must Close. A constructor and destructor seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199790/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-udp-server-restart-every-5-seconds).